# Get the next string after validating patterns using powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a text file and the contents can be:

```
debug --configuration "Release" \p corebuild
```

Or:

```
-c "Dev" debug
```

And now I have to validate the file to see if it has any pattern that matches `--configuration` or `-c` and print the string next to it

- Pattern 1 - It should be `Release`
- Pattern 2  - It should be `Dev`

How to achieve this in single command?

I tried below , but not sure how to extract only the release in the text , I only tried to see 1 pattern at a time

```
PS Z:\> $text = Get-Content 'your_file_path' -raw
PS Z:\> $Regex = [Regex]::new("(?<=\-\-configuration)(.*)")
PS Z:\> $Match = $Regex.Match($text)
PS Z:\> $Match.Value

 **Release /p net**
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are the arguments always inside double-quotes? and, can the arguments have spaces between them?

Comment: Yes they are in quotes and has spaces in between them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly and you only care about extracting the argument to the parameters and not which parameter was used, this might do the trick:

```
$content = Get-Content 'your_file_path' -Raw

$re = [regex] '(?i)(?<=(?:--configuration|-c)\s")[^"]+'
$re.Matches($content).Value
```

See https://regex101.com/r/d2th35/3 for details.

From feedback in comments `--configuration` and `-c` can appear together, hence [`Regex.Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=net-7.0) is needed to find all occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74311844/45375) with a PowerShell-only alternative:

Assuming that a matching line only ever contains `--configuration` OR `-c`, you can avoid the need for .NET API calls with the help of the [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator, which outputs a Boolean (`$true` or `$false`) to indicate whether the input string matches, and also reports the match it captures in the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches):

```bash
# Note: Omitting -Raw makes Get-Content read the file *line by line*.
Get-Content 'your_file_path' |
  ForEach-Object { # Look for a match on each line
    # Look for the pattern of interest and capture the
    # substring of interest in a capture group - (...) - 
    # which is later reflected in $Matches by its positional index, 1.
    if ($_ -match '(?:--configuration|-c) "(.*?)"') { $Matches[1] } 
  }
```

Note:

- `-match` only every looks for *one* match per input string, and only populates `$Matches` if the input is a *single* string (if it is an *array* of strings, `-match` acts *as a filter* and returns the subarray of matching elements).

  - [GitHub issue #7867](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7867) proposes introducing `-matchall` operator that looks for *all* matches in the input string.
- See [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/7giZ85/1) for an explanation of the regex.